# Python ide with omitting lines while debugging

Tags: python, debugging, ide

I have 3 lines and I want something like in visual studio where I can execute first line, and then by mouse move execution step to 3rd line and execute it without executing second line.

So in this case

```
print('a')
print('b')
print('c')
```

I want to have in an input:

```
a
c
```

Now I'm using wing ide 4 trial and it hasn't this option.

Comment: Why can't you just comment out the middle line and *then* run your code with the debugger?

Answer (score 2):

Wing IDE has a contributed add-on script that supports this:

http://wiki.wingware.com/DebugMoveProgramCounter

Drop it into the 'scripts' directory in your user settings directory (which varies in location but is listed 5th in Wing's About box) then select Reload All Scripts from the Edit menu.

Probably easiest to assign a key binding to the command jmp_line (in Keyboard / Custom Key Bindings preference), since it works relative to caret position.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the "Run to Line" command in [Eclipse Pydev IDE](http://pydev.org/), which is also free and open source.  Note that the debugger cannot jump to a line inside certain blocks, like for/while loops, finally clause, etc.

Given your example, use the following sequence of commands:

1. Set a breakpoint at `print('a')`.
2. Run your script in debug mode, menu **Run > Debug**.
3. The script should stop execution at `print('a')`. Run **Step Over** to execute that line.
4. When the execution pointer advances to the start of the `print('b')` line, move the cursor down to `print('c')` (or whatever line you want to execute next) and select menu **Run > Run to Line**. The execution pointer should jump to the start of that line.
5. Now run **Step Over** or **Resume** to execute `print('c')`.

Output of the above sequence:

```
a
c
```

It is also possible to do the same thing from the command-line using [Python debugger **pdb**](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html), specifically the **jump [lineno]** command.